# Elementary function evaluation

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, linear-algebra

I want to evaluate $f^{2011}g^{1994}(1/2)$ given f(x) = 1/(1-x) and g(x) = 1 - 1/x. My first step was to observe they are inverse functions, meaning fg(x) = x but I don't know how to proceed from here.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, that is very relevant. Since $f(g(x))=x$, then
$$f^{2011}(g^{1994}(x))=f^{2011-1994}(x)=f^{17}(x)$$
Now look what happens when you compose $f(x)$ with itself:
$$f(x)=\frac{1}{1-x}$$
$$f^2(x)=\frac{x-1}{x}$$
$$f^3(x)=x$$
This is very helpful. Now that we know that $f(x)$ inverts itself after three iterations, we can break our problem up into
$$f^{17}(x)=f^{3*5+2}(x)=f^3(f^3(f^3(f^3(f^3(f^2(x)))))=f^2(x)=\frac{x-1}{x}$$
And that should be the answer.